# Python round move to highest number possible, based on days (Full day, Half day)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python round move to the highest number possible, based on days (Full day, Half day)

> Full Day = 1, Half Day = 0.5

I want to move to the highest number based on decimal places.

E.g

```
>>> round(30/12, 2)
2.5  # 2 and half day

>>> round(20/12, 2)
1.67 # 2 Days

>>> round(15/12, 2)
1.25 # 1 Day

>>> round(4/12, 2)
0.33 # Half day
```

my code

```
total_leaves = 15  # 30,10,20,15
monthly_leaves = round(total_leaves / 12, 2)
monthly_leaves_final = 0

leave_one = int(str(monthly_leaves).split('.')[0])
leave_two = Decimal(str(monthly_leaves).split('.')[1])

if leave_two in [5, 5.0]:
    monthly_leaves_final = '%s.%s' % (leave_one, 5)

if leave_two > 5:
    monthly_leaves_final = '%s.%s' % (leave_one + 1, 0)

if leave_two < 5:
    monthly_leaves_final = '%s.%s' % (leave_one - 1, 0)
```

Comment: I don't understand why 1.67 rounds up to the next half, when 1.25 rounds down

Comment: I mean why does 1.25 -> 1 when 1.67 -> 2

Comment: @Alex028502 I need to distribute the leaves month-wise. So leave must be full day or half day

Comment: @Alex028502 if the division is 1.1 to 1.4 it will be 1 Full day. If 1.5 then 1 and half day
if 1.6 to 2.9 it will be 2 days

Comment: So the only way you can get a half day as an answer is if it is _exactly_ half a day? and otherwise, it's gets rounded off to the nearest full day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can round the value multiplied by 2 and then divide it by 2:

```
round(x * 2) / 2
```

Here is how it works:

```
lst = [round(i / 6, 3) for i in range(10)]
for el in lst:
    print(el, '\t->', round(el * 2) / 2)

# Output:
# 0.0   -> 0.0
# 0.167 -> 0.0
# 0.333 -> 0.5
# 0.5   -> 0.5
# 0.667 -> 0.5
# 0.833 -> 1.0
# 1.0   -> 1.0
# 1.167 -> 1.0
# 1.333 -> 1.5
# 1.5   -> 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Try this:-

```py
total_leaves = 15  # 30,10,20,15
monthly_leaves = round(total_leaves / 12, 2)
monthly_leaves_final = 0

leave_one,leave_two = str(monthly_leaves).split('.')
leave_one = int(leave_one)
leave_two= int(leave_two+'0') if len(leave_two)==1 else int(leave_two)
if leave_two == 50:
    monthly_leaves_final = '%s.%s' % (leave_one, 5)

elif leave_two > 50:
    monthly_leaves_final = '%s.%s' % (leave_one + 1, 0)

elif leave_two < 50:
    monthly_leaves_final = '%s.%s' % (leave_one, 0)
print(monthly_leaves_final)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to import math module:

```
monthly_leaves = round(total_leaves/12, 2)
monthly_leaves_final = 0

decimal = str(float(monthly_leaves)).split('.')[1]

if int(decimal) == 5:
    monthly_leaves_final =  (monthly_leaves)

elif int(decimal) > 50:
    monthly_leaves_final = (math.ceil(monthly_leaves))

elif int(decimal) < 50:
    monthly_leaves_final = (math.floor(monthly_leaves))
```